# Finding the inverse of the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 - 4x$ for $x \geq 2$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x)=x^2-4x$$ for $x\ge 2$. Find the inverse function indicating its domain and the range.

When I try to make $x$ the subject I get $+$and $-$ two answers for the inverse function. Is it the proper answer?
The answer I got is $$ x=2 
\pm \sqrt{y+4}.$$
 Is it correct and how do I determine the domain and range of the function? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You understand $f$ to be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ it is not invertible but the restrictions $f|_{\mathbb{R}^{\leq 2}}$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}^{\geq 2}}$ are invertible with inverses $g_1:\mathbb{R}^{\geq-4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\leq 2},x\mapsto 2-\sqrt{x+4}$ and $g_2:\mathbb{R}^{\geq-4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 2},x\mapsto 2+\sqrt{x+4} $  respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 - 4x$ for $x \geq 2$ has domain $\text{Dom}_f = [2, \infty)$.  We can find its range by completing the square.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^2 - 4x\\
     & = (x^2 - 4x + 4) - 4\\
     & = (x - 2)^2 - 4
\end{align*}
The graph of $y = (x - 2)^2 - 4$ is a parabola with vertex $(2, -4)$ that opens upwards.  The restriction that $x \geq 2$ means that the graph consists only of the right half of the parabola.  Since the graph is continuous and increases without bound as $x$ approaches $\infty$, the range of $f$ is $\text{Ran}_f = [-4, \infty)$.

Solving for the inverse yields
\begin{align*}
y & = (x - 2)^2 - 4\\
y + 4 & = (x - 2)^2\\
\sqrt{y + 4} & = |x - 2|
\end{align*}
Since $x \geq 2$, $|x - 2| = x - 2$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{y + 4} & = x - 2\\
2 + \sqrt{y + 4} & = x
\end{align*}
Therefore, the inverse function is
$$f^{-1}(x) = 2 + \sqrt{x + 4}$$
The domain of the inverse is $\text{Dom}_{f^{-1}} = [-4, \infty)$ and the range of the inverse is $\text{Ran}_{f^{-1}} = [2, \infty)$.

Notice that the domain of the function is the range of its inverse and the range of the function is the domain of its inverse.

Since the point $(a, b)$ is on the graph of $f$ if and only if the point $(b, a)$ is on the graph of $f^{-1}$, the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are symmetric with respect to the line $y = x$, as shown in the figure below.

[image: graph_of_quadratic_function_with_restricted_domain_and_its_inverse]

Answer (score 1):

yes we get $$x_{1,2}=2\pm \sqrt{4+y}$$ and it must be $$4+y\geq 0$$

Comment: But isn't against the rule that a function must not be many to one. For same y value you are getting 2 values right?

Comment: yes of Course, but your function $f(x)=x^2-4x$ is not monoton. so you will get two inverse

Comment: it is a Parabel in the form $$f(x)=(x-2)^2-4$$

Comment: We are given that the domain of $f$ is $[2, \infty)$, so we must take the positive root.